# end to end example of training (regression) model using SageMaker Python SDK from visual studio code

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I am aware of [SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html) but I am still struggling to find a simple end to end example of training and deploying a model from Visual Studio code using the SDK. Can anyone please provide some pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SageMaker Python SDK to cerate training jobs and deploy a model from VSCode. Please test this with any of the examples [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples).

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.